# AutoMapper with dynamic type: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-4

Answer: `CreateMissingTypeMaps` must be set to `true` to make dynamic mapping working.

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetDummies<T>(IEnumerable<dynamic> dummies)
    {
        var config =
            new MapperConfiguration(c => { c.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true; });

        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        return dummies.Select(mapper.Map<T>).ToList();
    }
```

---

I have wrapper around Entity Framework to perform queries to database. I want to allow user to select only required properties, but keep result of entity type.

This is dummy code (without using EF, but having same issue)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dummies = new[]
        {
            new DummyContainer
            {
                Name = "First",
                Description = "First dummy",
                DummyNumbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 },
                Foo = new FooThingy { Title = "Foo thingy" }
            }
        };

        var smallDummies = dummies.Select(d => new { d.Name }).ToList();
        List<DummyContainer> fullDummies = smallDummies.Select(Mapper.Map<DummyContainer>).ToList();

        Debugger.Break();
    }
}

class DummyContainer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> DummyNumbers { get; set; }
    public FooThingy Foo { get; set; }
}

class FooThingy
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Getting this exception:

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
<>f__AnonymousType0`1 -> DummyContainer
<>f__AnonymousType0`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] -> AutoMapperWithGenerics.DummyContainer

Destination path:
DummyContainer

Source value:
{ Name = First }
```

I'm bit stuck here, because documentation states that AutoMapper uses property names to map back to object: [Dynamic and ExpandoObject Mapping](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping).

Please note that code above is example. In my application, things get bit crazy as I'm actually using generics, e.g.

```
Mapper.Map<TEntity>
```

... and it should stay this way - I don't know what entity type is used. My expectation is just: map properties to existing type, if missing, set `default(T)`.

---

Edit: I tried to specify mapper from `dynamic` to `T`, almost full code here:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // ...

        var dumminator = new DummyService();
        IEnumerable<DummyContainer> bigDummies = dumminator.GetDummies<DummyContainer>(smallDummies);

        Debugger.Break();
    }
}

class DummyService
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GetDummies<T>(IEnumerable<dynamic> dummies)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(c => c.CreateMap<dynamic, T>());
        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        return dummies.Select(mapper.Map<T>).ToList();
    }
}
```

... this won't die on exception, however result is desperately empty (all properties have `default` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Mapper.DynamicMap<T>` instead of `Mapper.Map<T>` to map from dynamic or anonymous classes

```
List<DummyContainer> fullDummies = smallDummies.Select(Mapper.DynamicMap<DummyContainer>).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me this way, your suggestion is deprecated, but I was able to find how to set this via configuration object.

Comment: Right, it's an obsolete way. [Here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Migrating-from-static-API) is a documentation about the preferable way to configure this (which, as I can see, you have already found). I was glad to help.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of deprecated `DynamicMap` you can configure it globally.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true);
```

[Reference](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Migrating-from-static-API#unsupported-operations) to the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Hi similar answer but not forget to have a private constructor on your class and no do not validate inline maps.

```
       public class Player
       {
           private Player() {}.....

       }


   var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.ValidateInlineMaps = false;
                cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;

            }).CreateMapper();


            var player= mapper.Map<Player>(anonymousData);
```